# How to write a Mockito test for Java 8 Predicate and distinctByKeys in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, java-8, mockito

I have method for getting unique elements by using multiple keys like Employee id, name and age. Wrote a test case but filter section is not covering, so how to cover it?

```
 List<Employee> employees = getEmployees().stream()
                    .filter(distinctByKey(Employee::getEmployeeId, Employee::getEmployeeName, Employee::getEmployeeAge))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());



 private <T> Predicate<T> distinctByKeys(Function<? super T, ?>... keyExtractors) {
            final Map<List<?>, Boolean> seen = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            return t -> {
                final List<?> keys = Arrays.stream(keyExtractors)
                        .map(ke -> ke.apply(t))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                return seen.putIfAbsent(keys, Boolean.TRUE) == null;
            };
        }
```

Comment: If it's about code coverage, could you share the test case as well? That should explain.

Comment: Actually its a private method, so I have wrote a test case for the public method, which it will invoke, there I'm sending list of employees as input.

Answer (score 0):

If really need this part of code, you can use a lib Guava with the annotation @VisibleForTesting and you can call this method in the test.

https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/annotations/VisibleForTesting.html